# how to Authorize openiddict token generated from localhost/UserManagement API in other API localhost/SalesAPI

Tags: .net-core, oauth, openid-connect, openiddict

I have created openiddict token in dot net core api and that application is hosted at localhost/UserManagementAPI. When I try to authorize same API then I am able to do it. But when I try to use same token and Authorize other API localhost/SalesAPI it gives me unauthorized access error.

Token generation code is as below UserManagementAPI/startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenEndpointPath = "/authorize";
            options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;

           options.Provider.OnValidateTokenRequest = context =>
            {
                if (!context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType() && !context.Request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
                {
                    context.Reject(
                        error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.UnsupportedGrantType,
                        description: "Only grant_type=password and refresh_token " +
                                     "requests are accepted by this server.");

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }


                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ClientId))
                {
                    context.Skip();

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }


                if (string.Equals(context.ClientId, "client_id", StringComparison.Ordinal) &&
                    string.Equals(context.ClientSecret, "client_secret", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    context.Validate();
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            options.Provider.OnHandleTokenRequest = context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.IsPasswordGrantType())
                {

                    if (!string.Equals(context.Request.Username, "testusername", StringComparison.Ordinal) ||
                        !string.Equals(context.Request.Password, "testpassword", StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        context.Reject(
                            error: OpenIdConnectConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                            description: "Invalid user credentials.");

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }

                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Scheme.Name,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role);

                    identity.AddClaim(OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());


                    identity.AddClaim("userid", "1001",
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.AccessToken,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);


                    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(identity),
                        new AuthenticationProperties(),
                        context.Scheme.Name);
                    ticket.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));

                    ticket.SetScopes(OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile);

                    context.Validate(ticket);
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });
```

I have added below code to validate token in localhost/SalesAPI startup.cs

```
services.AddOpenIddict();
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Bearer";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Bearer";
        }).AddOAuthValidation();
```

I dont want to use authorization server.

with above code I am able to authorize other api's from localhost/UserManagementAPI (same api is responsible to generate a token)

please let me know If I am missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting you're not using OpenIddict in this snippet, but [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server), the low-level OpenID Connect server middleware that powers OpenIddict 1.x and 2.x.

If your resource server is located in a separate application, you'll need to configure that application to use the same ASP.NET Core Data Protection keys as the main application. Take a look at [ASOS - Token validation is not working when having separate authorization server and the resource server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844139/asos-token-validation-is-not-working-when-having-separate-authorization-server/44845613#44845613) for more information on how to do that.